# cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() is not working for python 3.7

Tags: python, opencv3.0

Following code is working for python 2.7 and 3.6. But it is not working for 3.7

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Modules (probably including opencv-contrib-python) are not yet updated to work with python3.7. so either downgrade or use an alternative library.